# Dual-booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10; can only use Bluetooth in one at a time

Tags: multi-boot, bluetooth

I'm using this laptop:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01HZT6AR0/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HZT6AR0)

As I said in the topic title, I am dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. I want to use my Bluetooth headphones. I usually use Windows for audio/video and Ubuntu for coding, and it ends up fine. However sometimes I pair my bluetooth headphones in Ubuntu also. When I do this, when I go back to Windows, my bluetooth driver doesn't function. If I go to device manager, it has the yellow "error" triangle. If I click properties, I get an error message like this one:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/bluetooth-adapter-device-cannot-start-code-10/209550e9-988b-487a-beed-009cbf96190b?auth=1

It says the device cannot start (code 10), due to power failure. If I disable and re-enable the driver, it doesn't fix the problem. However if I uninstall the driver completely, and then reinstall the same driver (the one recommended by ASUS's website for this laptop) it works fine, at least until I pair in Ubuntu again.

Any way around this?

Comment: Do you have fastboot disabled in Windows?

Comment: Hmm, I had it disabled previously, but it seems to have turned itself back on. I just shut it off again, I'll test the bluetooth later.

Comment: We have to do this in a couple machines for various reasons... It seems every major Windows update enables it again. I have also had Bluetooth issues in my laptop if I do not do a complete shutdown before booting the next OS, a reboot seems to cause issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can hsve your headphones paired with both OSes, wouldn't that be an better solution?

Here are guides to it. It is a bit different if it is a bluetooth Low energy device, and there are a couple of ways to do that.

[link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p), [link2](https://desktopi18n.wordpress.com/2018/02/02/bluetooth-mouse-in-dual-boot-of-windows-10-and-linux/https://) , [link3](https://huhuidong.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/pair-one-bluetooth-mouse-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-fedora/), [link 4](https://console.systems/2014/09/how-to-pair-low-energy-le-bluetooth.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.